# Node JS Express API Transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have a problem with my API transaction script, i want to send a multiple query, and use some commit to secure my transaction, but my script just work crazy and do his stuff 2 times with no logic for me.

I made 2 errors in my query (query and queryFactureReglement), when i launch my script, this is what i get :

HEY1

null false1

null false3

HEY7

HEY8

POST /reglement 200 231.449 ms - 23

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near ' '2019-11-18')' at line 1 false4

HEY2

HEY4false

HEY52

I dont understand what i did wrong, if you have an idea or a better way to do transaction.

Thanks for your help.

```
  //Envoie des requêtes en transaction pour rollback en cas d'erreur -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            console.log("HEY1");
            //On débute la transaction
            connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
                console.log(err + " " + flagError + 1);
                if (err && !flagError) {
                    console.log(err + " " + flagError + 2);//Transaction Error (Rollback and release connection)
                    flagError = true;
                        res.status(500).send(err);
                        //Failure
                } else {
                    console.log(err + " " + flagError + 3);
                    //Requête ajout réglement
                    try {
                        connection.query(query, null, function (err, results) {
                            console.log(err + " " + flagError + 4);
                            if (err && !flagError) {          //Query Error (Rollback and release connection)
                                console.log("HEY2");
                                connection.rollback(function () {
                                    flagError = true;
                                    res.status(500).send(err);

                                    //Failure
                                });
                            } else { //On récupère l'IDREGLEMENT si aucune erreur
                                console.log(err + " " + flagError + 5);
                                IDReglementInsert = result.insertId;
                                console.log("HEY3");
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log("ENFIN " + e);
                    }
                    //Requête ajout Facture_Reglement
                    connection.query(queryFactureReglement, [IDReglementInsert], function (err, results) {
                        if (err && !flagError) {          //Query Error (Rollback and release connection)
                            console.log("HEY4" + flagError);
                            connection.rollback(function () {
                                flagError = true;
                                res.status(500).send(err);

                                //Failure
                            });
                            //connection.rollback(function () {
                            //Failure
                            //  });
                        } else {
                            console.log("HEY42");
                        }
                    });
                    //Requête modificaiton facture
                    connection.query(queryFacture, null, function (err, results) {
                        if (err && !flagError) {          //Query Error (Rollback and release connection)
                            console.log("HEY5");
                            //  res.status(500).send(err);
                            connection.rollback(function () {
                                flagError = true;
                                res.status(500).send(err);

                                //Failure
                            });
                        } else {

                            console.log("HEY52");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            if (flagError) {
                connection.release();
            } else {
                //Aucune erreur, on commit
                connection.commit(function (err) {
                    console.log("HEY7");
                    connection.release();
                    //Success
                    console.log("HEY8");
                    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                    res.send("IDREGLEMENT : " + IDReglementInsert);
                    //Fin de la transaction
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many test, this is my final script if you need it:

```
 pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(" --- error 1: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                    connection.release();
                    res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                else {
                    //Query pour l'ajout du reglement
                    connection.query(query, null, function (err, result) {
                        //Erreur detecté, on roll back les query éxecutées, on relache la connexion et on envoie le message d'erreur au navigateur
                        if (err) {
                            connection.rollback(function () {
                                //console.log(" --- error 2: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                                console.log(" --- error 2: " + query);
                                connection.release();
                                res.status(500).send(err);
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            IDReglementInsert = result.insertId;
                            //Aucune erreur, on continue l'envoi
                            //Query pour l'ajout de la FactureReglement
                            connection.query(queryFactureReglement, [IDReglementInsert], function (err, result) {
                                  //Erreur detecté, on roll back les query éxecutées, on relache la connexion et on envoie le message d'erreur au navigateur
                                if (err) {
                                    connection.rollback(function () {
                                        console.log(" --- error 3: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                                        connection.release();
                                        res.status(500).send(err);

                                    });
                                } else {
                                    //Aucune erreur, on continue l'envoi
                                    //Query pour la modification du la facture
                                    connection.query(queryFacture, null, function (err, result) {
                                        //Erreur detecté, on roll back les query éxecutées, on relache la connexion et on envoie le message d'erreur au navigateur
                                        if (err) {
                                            connection.rollback(function () {
                                                console.log(" --- error 3: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                                                connection.release();
                                                res.status(500).send(err);
                                            });
                                        }else{
                                            //On commit car aucune erreur dans les query
                                            connection.commit(function (err) {
                                                      //Erreur detecté, on roll back les query éxecutées, on relache la connexion et on envoie le message d'erreur au navigateur
                                                    if (err) {
                                                        connection.rollback(function () {
                                                            console.log(" --- error 4: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                                                            connection.release();
                                                            res.status(500).send(err);
                                                        });
                                                    }

                                                    res.send("IDREGLEMENT : " + IDReglementInsert);

                                                    connection.release();
                                                });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```